# How to set transparent background to a PushButton using Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to create a GUI using `Qt Designer`. I have created a `MainWindow` and a `frame_1` (lets call it as frame_1 to differentiate from others) inside it. I set a border-image for the frame_1.

[image]

And now I place a PushButton on that frame_1 and it is having the same border image of frame_1. I am not able to change the background of the PushButton.

[image]

I know that there are lot of answers available on Internet but nothing seems to works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am using Qt Designer to make it. Don't know how to upload the ui and qrc file. Neverthless it is very easy to reproduce. Create a frame and add a border image and then try adding buttons to that frame.

Comment: @S.Nick I added additional information.

Comment: How are you setting the border-image for the frame in designer?

Comment: @Heike Right click on the frame and click `Change styleSheet -> Add Resource -> border-image`. I used the image as a Qrc resource file.

Comment: You could try changing the style sheet of the `QFrame` to something like `QFrame{ border-image: ...}`, or setting the border-image of the push button to None

Comment: @Heike Seeting the border-image of push button to None, makes it white and not transparent. Is there a way to make it transparanet?

Comment: @Heike Seeting the background-image of the push button to transparent solved the problem. Thanks for the hints :)